# Keycloak resource Authorization without adapter

Tags: playframework, keycloak

I have an angular2 client connecting to a web api implemented by Play Framework. The client is redirected to keycloak server to obtain token. I have followed Keycloak samples in their github project and the client side is working and obtaining a token. Unfortunately, I cannot find an adapter already implemented for Play Framework. So far I have the following code to check whether the user has access to the requested resource.

```
  val authzClient = AuthzClient.create()

  val request = new EntitlementRequest
  val permissions = new PermissionRequest
  permissions.setResourceSetName(resourceName)
  request.addPermission(permissions)

  val entitlementResponse = authzClient.entitlement(token)
    .get(resourceServer, request)
```

I am assuming if the server returned forbidden code the user with the token does not have access to the resource. Am I on the right track? Thanks.

**Update:**

I developed a custom action to check the header and validate the Authorisation toke:

```
import pdi.jwt.{JwtAlgorithm, JwtJson}
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}
import play.api.mvc.{ActionRefiner, Request, Result, Results}

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

case class UserRequest[A](user: User, request: Request[A])

object UserAction extends ActionRefiner[Request, UserRequest] {

  private val secret = "xxxxxx"
  private val algorithm = JwtAlgorithm.RS256

  override protected def refine[A](request: Request[A]): Future[Either[Result, UserRequest[A]]] = Future {
    request.headers.get("Authorization") match {
      case Some(headerToken) => {
        val token = headerToken.substring(7)

        JwtJson.decode(token, secret, Seq(algorithm)) match {
          case Success(validToken) => {
            val tokenJson = Json.parse(validToken.content)
            val user = extractUser(tokenJson)
            Right(UserRequest(user, request))
          }
          case Failure(ex) =>
            Left(Results.Unauthorized)
        }
      }
      case None => Left(Results.Unauthorized)
    }
  }

  private def extractUser(token: JsValue): User = {
    val username = (token \ "preferred_username").as[String]
    val firstName = (token \ "given_name").asOpt[String]
    val familyName = (token \ "family_name").asOpt[String]
    val name = (token \ "name").asOpt[String]

    User(username, firstName, familyName, name)
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you found a solution for the missing Play Framework adapter?

Comment: I ended up using jwt-play to validate the token on play server side. I can post the code if that helps.

Comment: yes it would be useful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might be a late answer but I hope this helps others.
The entitlement API has been removed after [version 4.3](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-8353). The following is the workaround I found when using Keycloak authorization without an adapter.

**Step 1:**

Define the policies and permission in the [Keycloak Admin UI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_resource_overview)

**Step 2**

Have an internal mapping of which HTTP paths belong to which resources and the required scopes for each path. This can be also saved in the [configuration file](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_enforcer_filter). When a particular route is invoked, call the Keycloak token endpoint to validate the claims of the access token.

```js
{
  "policy-enforcer": {
    "user-managed-access" : {},
    "enforcement-mode" : "ENFORCING"
    "paths": [
      {
        "path" : "/someUri/*",
        "methods" : [
          {
            "method": "GET",
            "scopes" : ["urn:app.com:scopes:view"]
          },
          {
            "method": "POST",
            "scopes" : ["urn:app.com:scopes:create"]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you are using an adapter and does not specify the path or resource, the adapter will internally search for the paths and resources [from Keycloak](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/f70af83fb628da80dc54968248af85b9ac25a45f/authz/client/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authorization/client/resource/ProtectedResource.java#L220).

**Step 3:**

Use the token endpoint to [get or evaluate](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_service_obtaining_permissions) the permissions. You can use `response_mode` parameter to either obtain the final decision (whether to provide access) or retrieve the entire permissions.

```sh
curl -X POST \
  http://${host}:${port}/auth/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" \
  --data "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket" \
  --data "permission=Resource A#Scope A"
```

If the authorization request does not map to any permission, a `403` HTTP status code is returned instead.

Comment: hi Nirojan, has keycloak provided any alternative to Entitlement api? We need one to overcome the latency issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have implemented a test [keycloak-nodejs-example](https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example) project with such check, using entitlement API and scopes. Keycloak returns `HTTP code 403 FORBIDDEN`, if user don't pass check for permissions.

https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example/blob/master/app.js

Anyway, Keycloak should return a success HTTP code for GET or PUT request, if user has a permission.
You can just check it using `curl`

http://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.3/authorization_services_guide/topics/service/entitlement/entitlement-api-aapi.html

You use resource names. A resource has `URI`. It will be funny to check that `URI` directly. But I still don't know how.

You should always provide `access_token` for every request to Keycloak. Sometimes, you can use `admin` credentials to get such token from Keycloak, using this URl: `auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token` (`master` is a name of the predefined realm).

But for Entitlement API you need a current user token, because of Keycloak should understand for witch user evaluate a permission.

You can decode `RPT` token using https://jwt.io/. This is just JSON with permissions. If you perform GET entitlement request, you will have all permissions. For `POST` request you will have evaluated permissions only or `FORBIDDEN 403`.

Comment: in my case the client is an anuglar2 application. This means that for every request from anuglar2 on my scala server I have to extract token from headers and send it keycloak to obtain user permissions for specific resource?

Comment: Meanwhile, the entitlement api return and rpt token. What is the use for this token? In the code above I am using the bearer token sent from the angular2 app.

Comment: @MeisamEmamjome I have updated my answer. I don't know which request is performed with this code `authzClient.entitlement(token).get(resourceServer, request)`. Did you check `FORBIDDEN` response?

Comment: Yes, i did. If the use is not entitled to the resource keycloak gives Forbidden response code. But I'm not sure if their adapters are implemented in the same way.

Comment: Seems like a roundtrip to the Keycloak server everytime an endpoint is hit is the only solution if one wants to use UMA